# Could not open JDBC Connection, Unable to get managed connection for java during load test

Tags: jboss, performance-testing, database-testing

Noticed below error during load test with multiple users and not in case of single SOAP request.

> Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to any of the following:

1. The datasource connection pool has not been tuned (e.g. max-pool-size and blocking-timeout-millis) correctly for the maximum load on the application.
2. The application is leaking connections because it is not closing them and thereby returning them to the pool.
3. Threads with connections to the database are hanging and holding on to the connections.

Make sure that the `min-pool-size` and `max-pool-size` values for the respective datasource are set according to `application load testing` and connections are getting closed after use inside the application code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've found the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) in your application, it seems that it cannot handle that many virtual users. The easiest solution would be raising an issue in your bug tracker system and let developers investigate it.

If you need to provide the root cause of the failure I can think of at least 2 reasons for this:

1. Your application or application server configuration is not suitable for high loads (i.e. number of connections in your [JBOSS JDBC Connection](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration) pool configuration is lower than it is required given the number of virtual users you're simulating. Try amending `min-pool-size` and `max-pool-size` values to match the number of virtual users
2. Your database is overloaded hence cannot accept that many queries. In this case you can consider load testing the database separately (i.e. fire requests to the database directly via JMeter's [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler without hitting the SOAP endpoint of your application.) See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about database load testing concept.